# How do I find the indices of the elements of one vector in a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

Suppose I have a 9x9 matrix A that that consists of integers. I have another matrix IDX that's 2500x4 and consists of the same integers in A. I want to find the indices of all the values in IDX in the matrix A.

Here's what I have:

```
for ii=1:length(IDX)
     Mat_idx=ismember(A,IDX(ii,:));
     [StatIdxX StatIdxY] = find(Mat_idx);
end
```

Now for each ii the StatIdxX and StatIdxY are the row and col indices of IDX in the matrix A. This is slow, and the culprit is `ismember`

Any thoughts on speeding this up?

Thanks.

Comment: your code has a bug, you are overwriting `[StatIdxX StatIdxY]` each loop iteration...

Comment: @natan This loop is actually nested in another loop so overwriting the [StatIdxX StatIdxY] is what I need to do. The general idea behind the code is to be able to expand a real solar data set that was laid out over a square mile. Each "solar station" corresponds to a ECEF coordinate system which is mapped to A. Since the stations represent point values within the geographical area, I can use knnsearch to help me find nearest neighbors at any arbitrary point in the grid. Then I can take the avg of those points to fill in the blanks. Thus, my original 45 stations can fill out a 25x25 grid.

Answer (score 3):

first flatten `A` with `A=A(:)`, that will make a single linear index instead of row,col.
Then just use logical indexing. For example:

```
B=zeros(size(IDX));
for n=1:numel(A)
B(IDX==A(n))=n;
end
```

Comment: @Robocop: thanks for the suggestion. This seems to work much better than my other loop.